# Calling Sonar from my java program

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have installed sonar server on my localhost. And I am able to run and analyse the java project. Even i have installed sonar plugin on eclipse.

But I want to run sonar from my java project(like simple java class) and should retrieve the sonar results and able to save it in database. I searched for the tutorial  but unable to find the answer for this. Please anyone can give sample code or resource where I can gain knowledge to overcome this task.

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;


import org.sonar.wsclient.Host;
import org.sonar.wsclient.Sonar;
import org.sonar.wsclient.connectors.HttpClient4Connector;
import org.sonar.wsclient.services.*;

public class SonarTask1{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //public void Hi(){
    String url = "http://localhost:9000";
    String login = "admin";
    String password = "admin";
    Sonar sonar = new Sonar(new HttpClient4Connector(new Host(url, login, password)));

    String projectKey = "java-sonar-runner-simple";
    String manualMetricKey = "burned_budget";

    sonar.create(ManualMeasureCreateQuery.create(projectKey, manualMetricKey).setValue(50.0));

    for (ManualMeasure manualMeasure : sonar.findAll(ManualMeasureQuery.create(projectKey))) {
      System.out.println("Manual measure on project: " + manualMeasure);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 things you can do from a Java program:

- launch a Sonar analysis: look into the [Sonar Ant Task](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-ant/blob/master/sonarqube-ant-task/src/main/java/org/sonarsource/scanner/ant/SonarQubeTask.java) (in method #launchAnalysis) to see how to do that very easily.
- retrieve results from the Sonar server: check the [Web API](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/web-service-api.html) for that purpose

Comment: may i know which are the dependencies i require for this. Dependencies in ""web service Client API" mentioned above are not downloading to my maven repo

Comment: You probably forgot to add a version to the dependency (this is not specified in the documentation as the versions change). You can use version 3.5.1.

Comment: ya i have added sonar-ws-client 3.5.1 and commons-httpclient 3.1 as external jars. and written a program as updated above but getting exceptionlike " java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpRequestBase
 at com.vxl.appanalytix.controllers.controllerClasses.SonarTask1.main(SonarTask1.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase.

Comment: may i know the reason. Whether have to add any other jars or dependencies

Comment: What is the projectKey used ? Is it the project name ?

Comment: The link to the Web Service Client API @ codehaus is defunct.Are there alternative sites? I'm having trouble finding them. Also is 5.1 the latest version or is there a more recent version?

Comment: I've updated both links. To know the latest version of SonarQube, check http://www.sonarqube.org

Answer (score -1):

About the " java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpRequestBase" you need this dependencies (Sonar WS uses them)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, I'd recommend when using Eclipse IDE, update maven project and check force update of snapshots/releases, because somehow org.apache.httpclient wasn't being able to be recognized by classpath